# Binary Search Tree, recursive function Exsists throw "core dumped" in comparation strings

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have the following the following structures to define an Binary Search Tree:

```
typedef struct Equipo {
    char nombre[50];
    char marcaMoto[30];
    int puntuaciones;
    struct Piloto pilotos[18];
    struct nodo* izquierdo;
    struct nodo* derecho;
} Equipo;

typedef Equipo Arbol;
```

the search in the tree will be performed by the string `nombre`, a `char [50]`. For create tree and insert data I use the functions:

```
Equipo* CrearEquipo(Equipo* e) {
    Equipo* n = (Equipo *) malloc(sizeof(Equipo));
    strncpy(n->nombre, e->nombre, 50);
    strncpy(n->marcaMoto, e->marcaMoto, 30);
    n->puntuaciones = 0;
    n->derecho = n->izquierdo = NULL;
    return n;
}

void InsertarEquipo(Equipo** arbol, Equipo* e) {
    if (*arbol == NULL) {
        Equipo* n = CrearEquipo(e);
        *arbol = n;
    } else {
        int comparado = strncmp(e->nombre, (*arbol)->nombre, 50);
        if (comparado > 0) {
            InsertarEquipo(&(*arbol)->izquierdo, e);
        } else {
            InsertarEquipo(&(*arbol)->derecho, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in `main` i use this functions to create test elements:

```
    Equipo* equipo = (Equipo *) malloc(sizeof(Equipo));
    strcpy(equipo->nombre, "C"); 
    strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "B"); 

    Arbol *arbol = CrearEquipo(equipo);

    strcpy(equipo->nombre, "B"); 
    strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "B"); 
    InsertarEquipo(&arbol, equipo);

    strcpy(equipo->nombre, "A"); 
    strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "B"); 
    InsertarEquipo(&arbol, equipo);

    strcpy(equipo->nombre, "E"); 
    strcpy(equipo->marcaMoto, "B"); 
    InsertarEquipo(&arbol, equipo);
```

Later, I create the recursive function for comprobate if exists in the tree:

```
int ExisteEquipo(Equipo* arbol, char nombre[]) {
    int comparado = strncmp(arbol->nombre, nombre, 50);
    if (!arbol) {
        return 0;
    } else if (comparado > 0) {
        printf("Menor ");
        return ExisteEquipo(arbol->izquierdo, nombre);    
    } else if (comparado < 0) {
        printf("Mayor ");
        return ExisteEquipo(arbol->derecho, nombre);       
    } else {
        printf("Igual ");
        return 1;  
    }
}
```

(The `printf's` are for test). When I call the exists function with:

```
void DeterminarExistencia(Equipo* arbol, char nombre[50]) {
    if (ExisteEquipo(arbol, nombre)) {
        printf("El nodo %s existe. \n", nombre);
    } else {
        printf("El nodo %s no existe. \n", nombre);
    }
}
DeterminarExistencia(arbol, "E");
DeterminarExistencia(arbol, "C");
DeterminarExistencia(arbol, "H");
DeterminarExistencia(arbol, "B");
```

but I always get the error: `Violación de segmento (core dumped) [Núcleo vaciado a un archivo]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
  int comparado = strncmp(arbol->nombre, nombre, 50);
```

You are asking if arbol is null after operating with it with the line above, so if it is null you are accessing a wrong memory address and that is causing the error.

Put it like this:

```
if (!arbol) {
    return 0;
int comparado = strncmp(arbol->nombre, nombre, 50);
```

Spanish:

Básicamente cambia el orden de lo que te he dicho arriba y deberia funcionar.